# Is it possible to have many domains on the same server with as many certificates?

Tags: linux, nginx, domain-name-system, lets-encrypt

In my nginx configuration `website.conf` I would like to have something like this:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name firstdomain.com seconddomain.com;
    ...
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/firstdomain.com/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/firstdomain.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/seconddomain.com/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/seconddomain.com/privkey.pem;
}
```

I did actually try it out but it does only serve in a secure way only one domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few problems here. First, HTTPS is served over port 443, not on port 80.

So your stanza where you should edit your TLS settings will be listening on port 443.

Secondly, you need to have a different `server block` for each domain. Each [server block is the equivalent of Apache Virtual Hosts](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/).

Third, if you're using Let's Encrypt, I would suggest that you get your domains working in each of their own `server blocks` over port 80 (without HTTPS), and then let Certbot do the magic for you, and configure the SSL certs & setup the Nginx config. There's several tutorials on how to do that.

Once you have the domains working over port 80, you would install Certbot (refer to https://certbot.eff.org/ for specific instructions on how to install for your distribution), and then run the following command: `certbot --nginx`.

Good luck!

Comment: Fixed the port, this is a configuration example, my config is far more complex and it's already on port 443 ;)
Now I'm going to try to split into two servers and see if it does the trick

Comment: Done, worked out nicely :D Thank you

Comment: Awesome! You're welcome.